# Heavy grinding noise when driving off in first gear

Tags: ford, transmission, noise, transit

I have a Transit 07 plate 2.2. Whenever I drive off in first gear the noise seems like it’s coming from the driver side but I have replaced everything from wheel bearing to driveshaft ... what else could it be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!